# Why do I have 90+ GB's of system on my mac?

Tags: macos, hard-drive, mac, storage

When checking the amount of storage on my mac the system category ranges from 40-90, essentially taking up the vast majority of my disk space.  Why is it so large and variable?  Is there any way to reduce it?

Here is an image of my storage breakdown:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple applications you can download that will tell you which folders are taking up how much space.

The first one is [Disk Inventory X](http://www.derlien.com/)

The second I advise is [OmniDiskSweeper](https://www.omnigroup.com/more)

Be careful with what you get rid of though. If it points to anything in /System then do not touch. If it points to /Library then there may be some things safe to remove but be very conservative and ask questions if needed.

Usually if /Library is large like that then there may be audio samples and loops installed for GarageBand taking up space, for instance. It had a lot of loop packages available for it and they install to /Library/Application Support/GarageBand